# How evaluate Dsolve solution by setting constants?

Tags: differential-equations

`Dsolve` returns

```
{{y[x] -> (1/(
   4 a))(12 a^3 x Sech[a x]^2 - 12 a^4 x^2 Sech[a x]^2 - 
     2 a^4 \[Pi]^2 x^2 Sech[a x]^2 + 2 a x C[2] Sech[a x]^2 + 
     4 a C[3] Sech[a x]^2 + 8 a^3 x^2 C[3] Sech[a x]^2 + 
     a^2 \[Pi]^2 Cosh[2 a x] Sech[a x]^2 - 
     4 a C[3] Cosh[2 a x] Sech[a x]^2 - 
     24 a^3 x Log[1 + E^(-2 a x)] Sech[a x]^2 + 
     24 a^3 x Log[Cosh[a x]] Sech[a x]^2 + 
     12 a^2 PolyLog[2, -E^(-2 a x)] Sech[a x]^2 - 
     6 a^2 Sech[a x]^2 Sinh[2 a x] - 
     2 a^3 \[Pi]^2 x Sech[a x]^2 Sinh[2 a x] + 
     C[2] Sech[a x]^2 Sinh[2 a x] + 
     8 a^2 x C[3] Sech[a x]^2 Sinh[2 a x] + 
     12 a^2 Log[Cosh[a x]] Sech[a x]^2 Sinh[2 a x])}}
```

How do I evaluate this for different choices of the `C`'s, to try to satisy boundary, asymptotic, and symmetry conditions?

Comment: You can do things like `{{y[x]->...}}/.{C[2]->421,C[3]->9}` to substitute different choices for your C's. Or you can study https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html to see how to give `DSolve` your boundary and initial conditions incorporated into the solution. From there you can evaluate the asymtotic and symmetry conditions.

Comment: Ok still won't evaluate y[0]

Comment: The result returned from `DSolve` isn't a function `y[x]` which immediately lets you say `y[0]` thinking that will evaluate the expression at `x==0`. In the same way as my first comment let you replace `C[2]` with `421`, if you want to replace `x` with `0` then try `{{y[x]->...}}/.x->0` and it instantly returns `{{y[0]==0}}` saying that expression is zero when x is zero. In some cases you may need to look up the documentation for `Limit` to see what the result will be as x approaches some value. I politely suggest you get an intro book to Mathematica and read it all. That will help you start.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I understand more now. In your situation I might consider finding a bright grad student with a solid background in Mathematica and paying them a modest amount to handle the Mathematica details correctly.

Comment: Bill, Thank you for the commands you shared.  I am just reverting to defining a function equal to the result; which is what I imagined y[x] was in the first place. I am trying to retire and finish up my math/fluid mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

[image]

### Code

```
ClearAll[y, x]
ode = y''[x] + 3 y'[x] + y[x] == Sin[x];
myY = DSolveValue[ode, y, x];
Manipulate[
 Plot[myY[x] /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}, {x, 0, 30}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, PlotRange -> All]
 ,
 {{c1, 1, "C[1]"}, -10, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c2, 3, "C[2]"}, -10, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c1, c2}
 ]
```

Update to answer comment

> just causes an echo; then rest doesn't work

You seem to have error in your code but hard to read in comment. It works for me:

```
ClearAll[y, x, a];
f[x_] := a*Tanh[a*x];
f1[x_] := D[f[x], x];
f2[x_] := D[f1[x], x];
f3[x_] := D[f2[x], x];
ode = y'''[x] == 
  12 f1[x]^2 - 4*y'[x]*f1[x] - 6*f[x]*f2[x] - 2*f[x]*y''[x] - 
   2*y[x]*f2[x];

myY = DSolveValue[ode, y, x];
Manipulate[
 Plot[myY[x] /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2, C[3] -> c3, a -> a0}, {x, 0, 
   100}, GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {{c1, 1, "C[1]"}, -10, 10, .1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c2, 0, "C[2]"}, -10, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c3, 0, "C[3]"}, -10, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{a0, -7, "a"}, -10, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c1, c2, c3, a0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. Something to study and implement.  unfortunately not until tonight PST. I did try but could not get the limit at infinity to evaluate. This is now the perturbation problem which I also need to check. I work on this at both ends of the day when dark outside. Excuse me and my ignorance of Mathematica. It is for windpower that I do unsponsored research

Comment: f[x : _] = a*Tanh[a*x]; f1[x : _] = D[f[x], x]; 
f2[x : _] = D[f1[x], x]; f3[x : _] = D[f2[x], x]; 
2 f1[x]^2 + 2*f[x]*f2[x] + f3[x]                                                                                
   ClearAll[y, x]; ode = 
 y'''[x] == 
  12 f1[x]^2 - 4*y'[x]*f1[x] - 6*f[x]*f2[x] - 2*f[x]*y''[x] - 
   2*y[x]*f2[x]                                                                                                                   myY = DSolveValue[ode, y, x]  just causes an echo; then rest doesn't work

Comment: Sorry Nasser should have checked . Your original has same problem in v9.

Comment: @simon it works for me. added code.

Comment: Sorry Nasser still doesn't work in v9. could put a0=1, it is the others need to determine with usual conditions. 2nd deriv 0 at x=0, first deriv does to zero at infinity. I got an answer with Dsolve direct but can't evaluate the limit at inf,  Can we compare answers first perhaps. Mine follows.

Comment: f[x : _] = a*Tanh[a*x]; f1[x : _] = D[f[x], x]; 
f2[x : _] = D[f1[x], x]; f3[x : _] = D[f2[x], x]; 
2 f1[x]^2 + 2*f[x]*f2[x] + f3[x]                                                                                         DSolve[{(y'''[x] == 
    12 f1[x]^2 - 4*y'[x]*f1[x] - 6*f[x]*f2[x] - 2*f[x]*y''[x] - 
     2*y[x]*f2[x]), (y[0] == 0), (y''[0] == 0)}, y[x], x]

Comment: h[x : _] = 
 1/(4 a) (a^2 \[Pi]^2 Sech[a x]^2 + 12 a^3 x Sech[a x]^2 - 
    12 a^4 x^2 Sech[a x]^2 + 2 a x C[2] Sech[a x]^2 - 
    24 a^3 x Log[1 + E^(-2 a x)] Sech[a x]^2 + 
    24 a^3 x Log[Cosh[a x]] Sech[a x]^2 + 
    12 a^2 PolyLog[2, -E^(-2 a x)] Sech[a x]^2 - 
    6 a^2 Sech[a x]^2 Sinh[2 a x] + C[2] Sech[a x]^2 Sinh[2 a x] + 
    12 a^2 Log[Cosh[a x]] Sech[a x]^2 Sinh[2 a x]); 
h1[x : _] = D[h[x], x]  h2[x : _] = D[h1[x], x]; 
h3[x : _] = D[h2[x], x]; Simplify[
 h3[x] - 12 f1[x]^2 + 4*h1[x]*f1[x] + 6*f[x]*f2[x] + 2*f[x]*h2[x] + 
  2*h[x]*f2[x]]

Comment: h1[0]  is C[2] but; Evaluate[Limit[h1[x], x -> Infinity]] =6 @ a=1 =24@a=2 so presumably 6a*a but won't say that (why?), so no solution with zero limit as Artes predicted , so original f solution cannot be perturbed. Also Nasser plot seems to show h linear with x at large x.

Comment: Nasser can you please rerun your plot for 1st deriv and with c[1]=0 a=1. Too many parameters presently. Also how do pause?

Comment: Unfair to close it whilst 3 questions not answered.